# How can I disable userinteraction behind subview?

Tags: ios, swift, subview, uicontainerview, user-interaction

In my project there is an *A* view, inside this view there is a container view that shows several buttons. If I click on these buttons another subview appears.

When the user clicks on the button and a subview appears, i want to disable all interactions outside of this subview that appears.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add your **another subview** to your container view. Add it to directy to A view or create second container view for your subview.
Then disable user interaction for your button's container view.

```
containerView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

After your subview appears, you can iterate to all its superview and set its user interaction to false.

```
UIView* temp = self.view.superview;
temp.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```

Now, u can recursively call this to all its superview to disable other functionality too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

1) Disable user intraction for backgroundView. But, you shoudn't add
   your new view as subview of backgroundView. you need to add the new view as subview of superview.

```
self.view.addSubView(YOUR_NEW_VIEW)
```

Then you have to disable user intraction for your backgroundView

```
YOUR_BACKGROUND_VIEW.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

2) Add one UIView as subview of your backgroundView with bounds of that view and backgroundColor as .clear

```
let tempView = UIView(frame: YOUR_BACKGROUND_VIEW.bounds)
tempView.backgroundColor = .clear
YOUR_BACKGROUND_VIEW.addSubView(tempView)
```

then add your new view to the subview of tempView

```
tempView.addSubView(YOUR_NEW_VIEW)
```

Choose the one which is suitable for you.
Hope this will help you